# Subsetting data between specific time points

Tags: r, time-series, subset

I have what is hopefully a simple question. I am looking to subset a data set by specific time points. I have data that came in over 24 hour time for a few months. 
e.g. 1 data point was received at 12:00pm, the next at 13:30pm, the next at 15:00pm etc... Below is an example or producing a data set similar to what I have, with a lot less factors.

```
x <- sample(1:48)
now <- Sys.time()
y <- seq(from = now,length.out = 48, by = "hours")

data <- data.frame(x,y)

data$Time <- format(data$y,"%H:%M:%S")

T1 <- filter(data,Time >= "06:00:00", Time <= "21:30:00") ## My code for filtering between time points
```

I have used the code below to filter out data points that fall between 6:00am and 21:30pm, which works fine and gives me the correct subsetted data.

```
T1 <- filter(data,Time >= "06:00:00", Time <= "21:30:00")
```

However a problem arises when I try and subset the data after 21:30pm till 6:00am.

```
T2 <- filter(data,Time <= "06:00:00", Time >= "21:30:00")
```

or

```
T2 <- filter(data,Time >= "21:30:00", Time <= "06:00:00")
```

This just provides me with 0 value in a the new T2 frame. I feel this may be a simple fix and I am just missing a slight change in my code.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Questions on routine R operations are off-topic here. If you can edit your question to include a minimal self-contained working example, you can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two separate logical conditions specified in

```
filter(data, Time <= "06:00:00", Time >= "21:30:00")
```

are combined with `&`. Also, both of these conditions are applied to the *same* day, which makes it clear why the result is empty (i.e., an event cannot be early and late at the same time). Thus, what you want to use is the OR operator given by `|`:

```
(T2 <- filter(data, Time <= "06:00:00" | Time >= "21:30:00"))
# x                   y     Time
# 1   4 2018-02-22 01:38:12 01:38:12
# 2   6 2018-02-22 02:38:12 02:38:12
# 3  26 2018-02-22 03:38:12 03:38:12
# 4  32 2018-02-22 04:38:12 04:38:12
# 5  40 2018-02-22 05:38:12 05:38:12
# 6   8 2018-02-22 21:38:12 21:38:12
# 7  30 2018-02-22 22:38:12 22:38:12
# 8  16 2018-02-22 23:38:12 23:38:12
# 9  36 2018-02-23 00:38:12 00:38:12
# 10 20 2018-02-23 01:38:12 01:38:12
# 11 22 2018-02-23 02:38:12 02:38:12
# 12 39 2018-02-23 03:38:12 03:38:12
# 13 12 2018-02-23 04:38:12 04:38:12
# 14 15 2018-02-23 05:38:12 05:38:12
# 15  2 2018-02-23 21:38:12 21:38:12
# 16 41 2018-02-23 22:38:12 22:38:12
# 17 27 2018-02-23 23:38:12 23:38:12
# 18 10 2018-02-24 00:38:12 00:38:12
```

Comment: Thank you Julius, exactly what I needed!